# Finding highest count by sum up of an attribute in an Json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs, json

I'm looking for clean and efficient way to get highest value count by sum up of all attributes in following json array.

`[{ "id":1, "material":2, "noMaterial":3, "negative":1 }, {  "id":2, "material":4, "noMaterial":3, "negative":3}, {  "id":3, "material":0, "noMaterial":1, "negative":1}]`

Expected Output:

`{ "noMaterial": 7 }`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: a for loop should do

Comment: You can use `map()` method like `yourArray.map(v=>{ ... })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not perfect way but may be it can be help to you.

```js
var data = [{ 
    "id": 1, 
    "material": 2, 
    "noMaterial": 3, 
    "negative": 1
}, { 
    "id": 2, 
    "material": 4, 
    "noMaterial": 3, 
    "negative": 3
}, {
    "id": 3, 
    "material": 0, 
    "noMaterial": 1, 
    "negative": 1
}];


let keyName = ['material', 'noMaterial', 'negative'];
let [material, noMaterial, negative] = [0, 0, 0];

data.map((v,i)=>{
    material += v.material;
    noMaterial += v.noMaterial;
    negative += v.negative;
});

const max = Math.max(material, noMaterial, negative);
const index = [material, noMaterial, negative].indexOf(max);

console.log(keyName[index]+':'+max)
```

Comment: I rewrite this code with more reliable so there is not need to write manually key name. [check here...](https://codepen.io/raeesh/pen/WNXdvmp)

Answer (score 0):

I defined a reusable hook that you can use on other attributes of your array as follows:

```
function getSum(keyName, data) {
  return {[keyName]: 
    data.reduce((acc, current) => {
      return acc + current[keyName]; 
    }, 0)
  };
}
```

and then call apply it on your data as follows:

```
getSum("noMaterial", data);
```

here is [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dfgym403/) for the code

Comment: sorry, I miss reading your question that you want the highest value.

Comment: output should be the key and value of highest count.